# POSTGRESQL WHERE query for multiple columns

Tags: php, postgresql

**I want to make a query which will search across four columns.**

*column names are:*

```
  cn00   |   cn01   |   cn03   |   cn12
```

---

*I have tried this:*

```
$load_elements = "cn00,cn01,cn03,cn12,cn22,cn23,cn29,cn30,cn46,cn49";
$search_keys_p = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$search_keys = $search_keys_p;
$search_keys = escape($search_keys);

$sql = "SELECT ".$load_elements." FROM cont_tab WHERE (cn00|cn01|cn03|cn12) LIKE :keyword order by cn46 asc";
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$search_keys = "%".$search_keys."%";
$statement->bindValue(':keyword', $search_keys, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

But it is not working out, Can anyone help me out with this......

Comment: Can you please explain, _what exactly_ doesn't work and provide an error message or the output you get vs the output you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but with some tries I have found the answer.

I have searched and worked on this for 3 hours and did not get a proper answer anywhere so I posted it here and luckily have found the answer myself.

ADD & MODIFY THE BELOW CODE TO THE QUESTION

***$columns = " concat_ws(' ', cn00,cn02,cn03,cn12)";***

***$sql = "SELECT ".$load_elements." FROM cont_tab WHERE(".$columns."LIKE :keyword) order by cn46 asc";***

**It might help some beginner like me...**

```
$load_elements = "cn00,cn01,cn03,cn12,cn22,cn23,cn29,cn30,cn46,cn49";
$search_keys_p = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$search_keys = $search_keys_p;
$search_keys = escape($search_keys);
$columns = " concat_ws(' ', cn00,cn02,cn03,cn12)";

$sql = "SELECT ".$load_elements." FROM cont_tab WHERE(".$columns."LIKE :keyword) order by cn46 asc";
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$search_keys = "%".$search_keys."%";
$statement->bindValue(':keyword', $search_keys, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

**PS:** *Any other easy methods to solve this differently are welcome*